# Remove `container` class programmatically with ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I would like all my pages except for 1 to have a class `container`

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>
```

I'd like to remove that class on the landing page (when the route is `/`). What is a DRY way to do this so I can still only set the container class once?

I could get the element by class name in the controller and remove it, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: I would leave only <div ng-view=""></div> inside <body> putting everything else including <div class="container"> inside views, even if it repeats

Comment: @Ali why would you do that?

Comment: in one of my early projects I left as you write, and CSS styles changed many times. Then customer wanted to add new pages with new layouts. I had to redo that part including CSS changes ((.

Comment: The @Ali idea is better because that doesn't require any js change...

Answer (score 1):

you can do

`<div ng-class="state.includes('/') ? '' : 'container' " >`

and assign .state in **.run** block

`$rootScope.state = $state;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngRoute to detect when your route is "/".

```
$routeProvider.when('/') and set a $scope.rootPath = true;
```

After you can use ng-class to remove the container class from the landing page.

```
<div ng-class="{container: rootPath != true}">
```

Edited, try like that:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            template: 'index.html',
            controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
                $scope.rootPath= true;
            }]
        })
        .when('/someOtherPage', {
            template: 'someOtherPage.html',
            controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
                $scope.rootPath= false;
            }]
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

Comment: where are you setting `$scope.rootPath`? Are you adding a controller onto the parent div?